# Request.ServerVariables("LOGON USER") returns empty

Tags: iis, authentication, web-config, authorization, windows-identity

**Web.config file**

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />     

<authorization>
  <allow users ="*" />
</authorization>
```

**IIS permissions**

```
(Unchecked)Enable ananymouse access
(Checked)Integrated windows authentication
```

**C# code,**

```
welcomeUser.InnerText = Request.ServerVariables.Get("LOGON USER");
```

What am I missing to be able to display Windows User ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the variable is `LOGON_USER` isn't it? (With underscore) See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp)

You *may* find that this gives you IUSR_MachineName though, so you might want to look up better ways of finding the *actual* logged in user, such as `User.Identity.Name` or by using `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`

Comment: Yes the problem was underscore. Thank you